# Error when trying to locate a json file, node (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

I'm getting an error when I try to find a file from my folder,

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969       
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'badwords.json'
```

Here is the current code.

```js
client.on("message", message => {

    const badwords =  require('badwords.json');
```

I can assure the file is in the same folder, people say it's a problem with my directory, I'm not too sure how to sort this out.

[image: Picture of my parent directory]

Thanks!

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: My bad, I tagged the wrong place, fixed it.

Comment: Use `./badword.json` instead of `badwords.json`

Comment: Thanks! That worked (not letting me mark as solution)